# How do I show the git status in the emacs bottom bar?

Tags: emacs, git

Is there a way to show the current branch, pluses, minuses, and authors in emacs status bar?  Something like:

`-UU-:**--F1  buildfile      Top (84,16)    (Ruby Paredit AC yas Fill) ---(git: master +2/-4 Jake Pearson`

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this:

```
(defadvice vc-git-mode-line-string (after plus-minus (file) compile activate)
  (setq ad-return-value
    (concat ad-return-value
            (let ((plus-minus (vc-git--run-command-string
                               file "diff" "--numstat" "--")))
              (and plus-minus
                   (string-match "^\\([0-9]+\\)\t\\([0-9]+\\)\t" plus-minus)
                   (format " +%s-%s" (match-string 1 plus-minus) (match-string 2 plus-minus)))))))
```

which puts `Git:master +9-2` in my mode line.

Not sure what you mean by author - would that be the author of the latest commit?  If so, this seems to work:

```
(defadvice vc-git-mode-line-string (after author (file) compile activate)
  (setq ad-return-value
        (concat ad-return-value
                (let ((author
                       (vc-git--run-command-string file "log" "-n1" "--pretty=format:%an" "--")))
                  (when author
                    (concat " " author))))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [emacs-powerline?](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline)

Comment: How will it help? Can you add a brief summary?